# Encountering a CryptographicException when console app is run from Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: c#, .net

I'm deploying a console app which gathers data on a user base and sends emails to our support team. There is a spreadsheet to read for which Google Spreadsheet Service is employed, therefore the corresponding class opens with the following lines:

```
const string serviceAccountEmail = "someemailaddresss";

var cert = new X509Certificate2(@"key.p12", "abigsecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

        var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
            new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail) {
                Scopes = new[] { "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds" }
            }.FromCertificate(cert));
```

I did not have any problems running it locally, nor were there issues when manually launching the executable on the AWS deployment machine. Now this task is to be automated and therefore was set up using Windows Task Scheduler, where it fails with the stack trace below.

```
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException
   at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Utils._QueryCertFileType(System.String)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.LoadCertificateFromFile(System.String, System.Object, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(System.String, System.String, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags)
   at (hidden).GoogleSpreadsheetReader.ReadBrokerList(System.String)
   at (hidden).Console.ReportEntryPoint..ctor()
   at (hidden).Console.ReportEntryPoint.Main(System.String[])
```

I have found answers which pertain to similar errors within web applications where the answer is to properly load the user profile for the app pool within IIS to enable the crypto subsystem. This however is a console app. Would could be the solution?

Comment: How did you configure the task to run? Which account is used to run your app? Have you checked the `Run with highest privileges`? Have you checked windows event journal? Have you tried to extend logging for the application?

Comment: The Administrator account was used and Run with highest privileges is checked. The event journal is where the above stack trace is coming from. The application has some basic logging but I am not sure how at this point it would really be useful, this exception occurs very early on in the execution cycle. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The cert seems to be a file expected to be in the current path. It probably isn't now that your start it from the Task Scheduler.

Comment: But the cert file does reside in the same directory as the exe.

Comment: The description provided is meaningless. You could `try {} catch(Exception e) {  }` earlier, and print the error message somewhere (e.g. to the file).

Comment: Good thinking, @stukselbax. Will try that.

Comment: Hm. When running locally and breaking the code on purpose, I catch the error and print it to a file which I am able to open. When running on AWS and the Task Scheduler, no file is generated, and all I see are NullReferenceExceptions in Event Viewer (since I'm setting the initial values of cert and credential to null before initializing them in the try block).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And here was the actual solution: While configuring the task in Task Scheduler, indicating the exe directory under "start in" in the Actions tab fixed the issue. Even though "start in" is marked as an optional field and the path to the executable was obviously initially provided.